# Meaning of "Sell it on"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

In maybe first 4~5 minutes in the movie *The Prestige*, a magician was died in his own magic trick, the witness told the jury that it is someone's fault, then a jury asked the witness the mechanism behind the magic trick, then the witness said the following:

> This trick is one of the most sought-after illusions in this business. I have the right to **sell it on**. If I reveal the method here, then the trick is worthless.

What does **sell it on** mean?

I found the phrase **sell someone on something** to mean to persuade someone that something is good, valuable, or useful, for example:

> The filmmakers sold me on the idea that my book would work on the screen.

But it does't apply here.

Comment: [sell on](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sell-on) - to sell something after buying it from someone else - *They buy it at a low price and **sell it on** for a huge profit*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sell it on" means to sell it after previously having bought it from someone else.

> "He bought an old house, decorated it, and sold it on."

I can't remember who the witness was in the movie, and whether he had bought the mechanism from someone else, but the phrase could also be used for something that he had built himself.

Answer (score 0):

to sell something after buying it from someone else